# How to calculate CRC_B in C#

Tags: c#, crc, iso

How to calculate CRC_B encoding in C# as described in ISO 14443?
Here is some background info:

> CRC_B encoding
>   This annex is provided for explanatory purposes and indicates the bit patterns that will 
>   exist in the physical layer. It is included for the purpose of checking an ISO/IEC 
>   14443-3 Type B implementation of CRC_B encoding. Refer to ISO/IEC 3309 and CCITT X.25 
>   2.2.7 and V.42 8.1.1.6.1 for further details. Initial Value = 'FFFF'

- Example 1: for 0x00 0x00 0x00 you should end up with CRC_B of 0xCC 0xC6
- Example 2: for 0x0F 0xAA 0xFF you should end up with CRC_B of 0xFC 0xD1

I tried some random CRC16 libraries but they aren't giving me the same results. I didn't get the same results from online checks either like in [here](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reversed this from the C code in [ISO/IEC JTC1/SC17 N 3497](http://wg8.de/wg8n1454_17n3497_Ballot_3rdCD14443-3.3.pdf) so its not pretty but does what you need:

```
public class CrcB
{
    const ushort __crcBDefault = 0xffff;

    private static ushort UpdateCrc(byte b, ushort crc)
    {
            unchecked
            {
                byte ch = (byte)(b^(byte)(crc & 0x00ff));
                ch = (byte)(ch ^ (ch << 4));
                return (ushort)((crc >> 8)^(ch << 8)^(ch << 3)^(ch >> 4));
            }
    }

    public static ushort ComputeCrc(byte[] bytes)
    {
            var res = __crcBDefault;
            foreach (var b in bytes)
                    res = UpdateCrc(b, res);
            return (ushort)~res;
    }
}
```

As a test, try the code below:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args) 
 {
     // test case 1 0xFC, 0xD1
     var bytes = new byte[] { 0x0F, 0xAA, 0xFF };
     var crc = CrcB.ComputeCrc(bytes);
     var cbytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(crc);

     Console.WriteLine("First (0xFC): {0:X}\tSecond (0xD1): {1:X}", cbytes[0], cbytes[1]);

     // test case 2 0xCC, 0xC6
     bytes = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
     crc = CrcB.ComputeCrc(bytes);
     cbytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(crc);
     Console.WriteLine("First (0xCC): {0:X}\tSecond (0xC6): {1:X}", cbytes[0], cbytes[1]);


     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting following exception when I try to run this test: System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
It points to line: ch = (byte)(ch ^ (ch << 4));

Comment: What byte values are you using that's creating the exception?  I've tried a ton of variations but I cannot get an overflow.  It may be that overflowing is necessary, I'm not familiar enough with C compilers to know if that is the default.  I have modified the code to reflect this.

Comment: That was the case. I had to uncheck the "Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow" option from the project properties to make this work with SharpDevelop IDE.